# Create error pages from search php script

Tags: php, mysql, search

Is it possible to change my search script to direct the client to a different page if there is an error?

Instead of having a text appear "No result have been found!", I would like them to be directed to search_error1.php.

Instead of having a text appear "You have not entered the search field", I would like them to be directed to search_error2.php.

```
<?php

$error = '';

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
if (!empty($_POST['reg'])) {

$record = $_POST['reg'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg_add WHERE reg='" . mysql_real_escape_string($record) . "'");
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($result != 0) {

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$first_name = $row['first_name'];
$last_name = $row['last_name'];
$reg = $row['reg'];

} else {$error = 'No result have been found!';}

} else {$error = 'You have not entered the search field, <a     href="javascript:history.back(1)">Go back</a>.';}

}

if (!empty($error)) { echo $error; } 

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

Use `header()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
} else { header("Location: search_error1.php"); exit; }

} else { header("Location: search_error2.php"); exit; }
```

Your code (+ intended) would look like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['reg'])) {

        $record = $_POST['reg'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg_add WHERE reg='" . mysql_real_escape_string($record) . "'");
        $result = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($result != 0) {

            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

            $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            $reg = $row['reg'];

        } else {
            header("Location: search_error1.php");
            exit;
        }

    } else {
        header("Location: search_error2.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer, you can do that by clicking on the check box outline to the left of this answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo`ing the error, use a header redirect. Example.

`header("Location: search_error1.php");`